# pass div id or class to customise form in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I want to change how the form looks like. For that in html I would change input tag with css. In rails I'm trying to add div to the form, however with no success. How to make it right?

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :degree_cont, "...by degree (e.g. bachelor)" %>
  <%= f.text_field :degree_cont, size: 15 %>
</p>

<p class="button"><%= f.submit "Search" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a class to the search form in rails, and then style it in CSS, rather than add divs. Like this:

`<%= search_form_for @search, :html => { :class => "your-class-here" }  do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to css I suggest you check out Twitter bootstrap.

Try adding `gem bootstrap-sass` to your `Gemfile`. 
Then go to http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms. 
I'm guessing the `.form-search` class is what you are looking for.

You can use code similar to this to create a form using this css class:

```
<%= form_for(@search, :html => { :class => 'form-search' }) do |f| %>
...
```

Comment: How than I supposed to change form with help of css? I guess I need to add div inside form_form or text_field, however not sure how to make it!